# QML Row how to transition items from the right?

Tags: qt, qml

So I have a Row connected to a model and a delegate, when a new item is appended to the row I'd like to animate it from the right.  This works if the width of the new item is "58":

```
Row {
    id: myRow
    add: Transition {
        NumberAnimation {
            properties: "x"
            from: width + 58
            easing.type: Easing.OutBounce
            duration: 1000
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: myModel
        delegate: myDelegate
    }
}
```

How do I set that width to the width of the item being added instead of hard-coding it?

Comment: Is the width of the delegate item variable? I mean, could you possibly set it as a property of the Row item and then refer to it in the delegate?

Comment: The delegate item is an avatar image loaded from a url.  They all seem to be 48 px now, but I don't know what they'll be next year..

Comment: what about `layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft`